# Outer join on multiple tables on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join, self-join

I'm writing a recursive algorithm. It's taking data from 4 periods in the last year, and creating a resultset.
The issue is that not all scenarios return 4 periods.
So, I've done an set of 4 selects on the table, used an outer join to connect them. Their joined on the PK. However, they're all joined to the first datapoint. Sometimes this datapoint doesn't exist, which throws a wrench in my join.
Is there an easy way to do a full outer join on 4 tables using a PK with doing 16 where clauses and outer joining them with (+)
Actually, does (+) even work on sql server?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Why not just use a Union?

Comment: Did you try a + before you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a complete dataset containing all periods in the previous year.   *You could do this by using something like SELECT DISTINCT PERIOD FROM (SELECT PERIOD FROM SetA union SELECT PERIOD FROM SetB UNION SELECT PERIOD FROM SETC etc...) AS COMPLETESET"

Then left join against the COMPLETESET all other datasets on period.

The data points that do not exist in the joins will return null values.

Comment: Awesome, that works!
I actually created an extra table with all the potential PKs, and joined everything to that.
This is an awesome trick for recursive self joins, thanks!